# Use jQuery to attach JSON to a form and submit it

Tags: jquery, json, forms

Given this empty form, how would I use jQuery to attach a JSON object as params and then submit it? The form should standard submit, not AJAX.

```
<form action="/comments" method="post" id="comments_form">
  <submit>Post</submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your JSON object is the `myData` variable (and you make [`JSON.stringify`](http://json.org/js.html) available):

```
$('#comment_form').submit(function() {
    var $hidden = $("<input type='hidden' name='myData'/>");
    $hidden.val(JSON.stringify(myData));
    $(this).append($hidden);
    return true;
});
```

The above code creates a hidden form input on the fly and gives its value the string representation of your JSON object, then appends it to the form right before submission.

Comment: myData is already the complete hash of form data. The example you give will submit it as :comment[:myData[myData]], but it needs to be submitted as :comment[myData].

Comment: It will not function if there are special characters in the original Json object such as `'` `"` or `<`.
You may use `$hidden.val(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myData)))` or an hidden textarea instead of a hidden input